# Changing label according to selected value in combo box

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

suppose i have two fields in my table or model

1. Mode : it can have two type of  Mode  Audio and Script
2. path : this field will have path of a file Either an audio file or script

i am just exploring it so this is just a dummy table. What i want to know is if it is possible that if i choose Audio then next label should be "Select audio file" and when i choose Script label should be "Select script path"
I know how to do it manually but can django do it automatically for me by just specifying right model and form..?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with Django?

Comment: @Bibhas i am trying to know if this is possible i mean if django support for this type of dynamic behaviour.? Want to know the right direction to try.

Comment: So you don't have a problem yet. You're not stuck. If you want to know something is possible, please try first and then ask if you're stuck.